# Azure Functions + node.js - cannot find module

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions

I've created an app and a function with Azure CLI, which has a proper structure, so:

```
/host.json
/local.settings.json
/mycustomfunction/function.json
/mycustomfunction/index.js
/mycustomfunction/package.json
/node_modules
```

Source code gets downloaded from BitBucket, deployed with Kudu, built (*node_modules* are fetched, azure is one of them), everything is green.

When it comes to dependencies there is only one - `"azure": "^2.0.0-preview"`

But when I run the function on Azure, I get error

`2017-09-08T13:59:06.091 JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.
2017-09-08T13:59:06.216 Exception while executing function: Functions.mycustomfunction. mscorlib: Error: Cannot find module 'azure'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)`

The same function works fine locally when run with `func host start`...

What am I doing wrong? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the problem was with the Shared/Consumption model for Azure Functions. I've noticed that when running `npm install`, most of the time the process would timeout with no packages showing up in the `node_modules` folder leaving only the `.staging` folder behind. After creating a new Function App with with dedicated App Service Plan, everything works as expected.

**Another (potentially better) solution** is to include `azure-sb` module, `instead of azure`. It provides enough capabilities to query Azure Service Bus, while it's significantly smaller and Kudu is able to fetch it even with Shared Tier resources.

Comment: I was about to try installing individual modules when it worked the second time.  Thought that might help with the timeout issue but I must have squeaked under the wire the second time.

Comment: Another option would be to try dropping a zipped file of the node_modules using Kudu.  Have not tried it so I don't know if that will help.

Comment: If you stick the Shared Consumption model, sometimes you have to try a few times.  Delete `node_modules`, `npm i`, work?, no: repeat.

Answer (score 4):

The root cause should be because you haven't not run the **npm install** command in the Kudu console of your function app to install the necessary node modules defined in your function app's package.json.

Follow this guide: [Node version and Package Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node#node-version-and-package-management)

Below are some highlights from the reference guide above.

> After the package.json file is uploaded, run the **npm install** command
>   in the **Kudu remote execution console**.
>
> This action downloads the
>   packages indicated in the package.json file and restarts the function
>   app.
>
> After the packages you need are installed, you import them to your
>   function by calling `require('packagename')`, as in the following
>   example:

```
// Import the underscore.js library
var _ = require('underscore');
var version = process.version; // version === 'v6.5.0'

module.exports = function(context) {
    // Using our imported underscore.js library
    var matched_names = _
        .where(context.bindings.myInput.names, {first: 'Carla'});
```

Comment: Yes, I've followed this tutorial already and I've run npm install. I also think that npm install is run automatically when you fetch source code from source code repository. But somehow module isnt found yet.

Comment: OK, I tried another app with the same dependency (azure) and from what I see npm install has some issues. At least it looks like I get a .staging folder instead of packages inside node_modules folder. I will try to put dependency on specific module that I need vs on azure complete module.